# angular2 event defined in a service is not getting caught in the component

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am firing an event using EventEmitter in my angular2 service. But this event is not getting caught in my component.

My service(file is - 'app.service.ts'):

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
  private _event:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => this._event.emit("hello"),1000);
  }
  getEventRef(){
   return this._event;
  }
}
```

My component(file is './app.component.ts'):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {AppService} from "./app.service";

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: '<h1>App</h1>',
providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private _service:AppService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    _service.getEventRef()
      .subscribe(res => alert(res));
  }
}
```

But I am not getting the alert that I should be getting in my component. I am not sure if the service is firing event with .emit api.

Answer (score 2):

The `ngOnInit` hook method can't be used for services but only for components. For services you can use the constructor:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
  private _event:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(){
    setTimeout(() => this._event.emit("hello"),1000);
  }
  (...)
}
```

Another comment. It's better to use the `EventEmitter` only for component communications. In your case, use either `Observable` or `Subject`:

- with the `Observable` / `Observer` classes

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class AppService{
    private _event:Observable<string> = Observable.create((observer:Observer) => {
      this._event$ = observer;
    }).share();
    constructor(){
      setTimeout(() => this._event$.next("hello"),1000);
    }
    (...)
  }
  ```
- with the `Subject` class. This class is both observable and observer.

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class AppService{
    private _event:Subject<string> = new Subject();
    constructor(){
      setTimeout(() => this._event.next("hello"),1000);
    }
    (...)
  }
  ```

You should also use the following in your component:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this._service.getEventRef()
    .subscribe(res => alert(res));
}
```

instead of:

```
ngOnInit(){
  _service.getEventRef()
    .subscribe(res => alert(res));
}
```

See these plunkrs:

- https://plnkr.co/edit/zIEKhreHcBTJzbkpjSOJ?p=preview (EventEmitter)
- https://plnkr.co/edit/KiSRB38OrDv59xjSEeS6?p=preview (Subject)

Comment: Hi, I want to use Observables also, don't want to use EventEmitter. But I can't get proper documentation on how to user Observables. Can you plz reply with some link from where I can learn to implement Observables with rc1 version of angular2?

Comment: I removed ngOnInit. Still not working with EventEmitter.

Comment: Do you replace `ngOnIniy` by `constructor`? FYI subjects are observables ;-) I added a sample with a raw observable. I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: Yes I replaced ngOnInit by the constructor. Then called a private method within constructor. That private method is firing setTimeout with delay of 1 second. In this setTimeout I am writing this._event.emit("hello")

Comment: In your component, you should use `this._service.getEventRef()` instead of `_service.getEventRef()`. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/zIEKhreHcBTJzbkpjSOJ?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks Thierry. I forked your plunk and modified it. What I exactly wanted to do is to fire the event as soon as all of my http calls in the service completes. I couldn't make a plunkr earlier as my plunkr couldn't detect angular2/core library. The plunkr is: https://plnkr.co/edit/y95mFC?p=preview . Please check this one. Sorry for being such a pain, should have explained this to you earlier. Previously I thought EventEmitter is not working with any async calls.

Comment: No worries! It's a bit strange since the event is correctly fired and received in the callback only if the request is successful (for example by loading the plunkr with the http protocol). When there is error, it's not received :-(

Comment: Yes, success callback is working in plunkr but not in my code. I cannot share the code. I can just tell you that there are 4 http calls, and after their completion(asynchronously), I have to fire an event to know the same in my component. The component will show some text to the user then.

Comment: To be notified when a set of observables completes, you can use `Observable.forkJoin([ obs1, obs2, ...])`.

Comment: angular2 and rxjs has made this very complex. I can't fire/catch an event on this condition. It should have been simple.

Comment: I think this should be cleaned up: `The ngOnInit hook method can't be used for services but only for components. For services you can use the constructor:`.  I thought angular 2 actually promoted service initialization/subscriptions in the onInit vs the constructor so they could be queued up outside of initialization.